# The conversion of the varchar value overflowed an int column using REPLACE

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I try to trim records that have line breaks in the end sometimes I got an errors with specific codes. Where is mistake can be?

```
SELECT f.Name FROM Firms f WHERE Replace(Replace(f.Code,CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),'') = ".$firm_code."
```

Error1 :

> The conversion of the varchar value '45308040080' overflowed an int
>   column.

Error2:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: ".$firm_code." should be a string. It seems to be an int value so the left part of the expression is converted to int too and you get that error message.

Comment: Is this a `PHP` script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation:**

The reason for your error is that with this syntax:

`SELECT f.Name FROM Firms f WHERE Replace(Replace(f.Code,CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),'') = ".$firm_code."`

SQL Server makes an implicit data type conversion, because you are trying to compare varchar and integer values. Based on [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), all varchar values are converted to integer.

The next example demonstrates this issue. If `f.Code` column has a value `'45308040080'`, the conversion to integer will raise a `'The conversion of the varchar value '45308040080' overflowed an int column.'` error:

```
SELECT 1
WHERE Replace(Replace('45308040080', CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), '') = 1
```

**Solution:**

Probably the best approach is to compare these values as text. This seems to be a `PHP` syntax, so next lines may help to generate the correct statement:

```
<?php
...
$stm = "
    SELECT f.Name 
    FROM Firms f 
    WHERE Replace(Replace(f.Code,CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),'') = '".$firm_code."'";
...
?>
```

Comment: Omg, what a stupid mistake (facepalm). Thank you so much!

Comment: @Zhorov . . . No.  The best solution is to use parameters and pass in the values with the right types.  I don't understand how such advise gets upvoted.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I agree (about the parameters), but it was a guess (about using PHP) and I really don't know where the value for $firm_code comes from. That's why the answer is about solving this conversion error (tags are sql and sql-server). Thanks for this comment, I should be more precise in my future answers.

Answer (score 1):

cast your column as `bigint`

```
SELECT f.Name FROM Firms f WHERE Replace(Replace(cast(f.Code as bigint),CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),'') = ".$firm_code."
```

**testing:**

```
select Replace(Replace(cast(cast('45308040080' as varchar(50)) as bigint),CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),'')
```

Comment: Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

Comment: tried this one select Replace(Replace(cast(cast('45308040080' as varchar(50)) as bigint),CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),''), its working